# How do I proceed with the uploading of a relational spatial database from PostGIS to Geoserver?

Tags: relational-database, postgis, geoserver

I'm new to relational databases, so I would like to ask how do I have to proceed with the uploading of  relational tables from PostGIS to Geoserver. In particular, I have 5 tables that are linked with primary and foreign keys and of course one of them has the geometry column.So, when I chose in Geoserver the connection to my db, I saw all the tables as it is in PostGIS (five different tables). If I continue with the publishing, the 4 out of 5 tables will not have geometry columns, cause they are not likned (at the level of Geoserver).So, how I have to prepare my db in order the tables appeared in Geoserver combined and basically publish only one shp which will be the merge of the 5 tables of the relational db.I thought to create an extra table linked to the others, but that creates a redundancy in the db.
Therefore, which is the proper way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view in the DB and publish this view.

Alternatively, you can publish the 5 tables and create a [view in Geoserver](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) directly.

Comment: Will the view be up to date with every changes that I willl make in the db?

Comment: @Newstudent yes, a view is just a pointer to the data in the underlying tables. See this [tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-views/)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Hello again!I'm faced with a problem!Either I am creating a view from PostGIS or via Geoserver, the Native BBox gives values (-1,-1,0,0) and also the Lat/Lon BBox doesn't have the correct ones.The view in the db runs correctly, merging all the 5 tables.Then again, I notice that when I create the view via Geoserver, the column of SRID doesn't show up to set it from there.Therefore, I tried to publish only the table with the geometry column to see if it works and the computing of native bbox was correct.I am working on a remote db and I have all the privileges for select etc.